# Navigate between UiNavigation Controller and Uitabbar Controller in iOS 4.3

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, ios5, iphone-sdk-4.3

In my app,I'm able to navigate the controllers from a uinavigation controller to a tabbar item's navigation controller(Inside my tabbar controller each tabbar item has seperate uinavigation controller)  but back to navigation controller is not working.

I tried both pushviewcontroller and presentModalViewController but in both cases the back navigation is not working.

This problem occurs only in iOS 4.3 but works fine in iOS 5

I tried the below code to dismiss the modalviewController:

```
 [self  dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: You did something wrong, it should be working. Do you see the navigation bar at root view controllers ? maybe you can show the tab bar items initialization with navigation controllers ?

Comment: @A-Live Both navigation bar and tabbar controllers are visible.When I debugged by clicking the button,every line of code gets debugged correctly,but that doesn't make any effect on screen.